# WordPress does not go to correct address to find a file

Tags: ajax, wordpress, plugins

I am running WordPress on my localhost and trying to send request from a file of my plugin to another file called photos.php using ajax, I have correctly written the address of file in xmlhttp.open function but it runs into following error.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /wordpress/wp-admin/wp-content/plugins/myphoto/photos.php was not found on this server.
```

the actual address of the file is /wordpress/wp-content/plugins/myphoto/photos.php

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","wp-content/plugins/myphoto/photos.php?c="+option,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Does that page redirect to /wp-admin/... perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the absolute path:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/myphoto/photos.php?c="+option,true);
```

Your error implies you're using the relative path. Directory `/wordpress/wp-admin/wp-content...` does not exist.